# adding fill in the blank option in Angular ngx-editor

Tags: angular, ngx-editor

I am using ngx-editor in Angular 11/12. I require to add a fill-in-the-blanks option at the cursor position.

essentially I wish to add  HTML markup at the cursor  position on the click of a button.

any help?

Comment: A little bit vague. You mean on click in the editor, paste some text into the editor?

Comment: I have a button outside the editor. When i click on that, a FIB (input) should be added at the cursor position inside the editor. It is like in the same way we add controls from the editor toolbar.

Comment: But when you click a button outside the editor, your cursor is no longer inside the editor. How to determine the location where to paste it? Or maybe you toggle button to paste (make it active) and on next click inside the editor, input's text will be pasted to the editor at cursor location?

Comment: yes. if you can help me these two

1. How to find cursor position in editor 
2. How to add HTML in editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an external input and button to copy. Input gets the text and copy button means that if copying is enabled, on click to editor, text from input will be added to editor click location on next click.

```js
  myInput: string;
  isCopy = false;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) onClick(e){
    console.log(e);
    if (this.isCopy) {
      e.innerText = e.innerText + this.myInput
    }
  }
```

```html
    My input: <input [(ngModel)]="myInput"> 
    <button (click)="isCopy = !isCopy" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': isCopy ? 'red' : '' }">copy!</button>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-editor-qydmny?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html